# Design solution for working with multiple instantiations at the same time

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I don't know if my title is correct. But here's what I want to know.

I have a Download class that returns certain events and has a couple of methods. Each instance of Download class can download a single file. And all those events and methods are related to the file being downloaded.

As it's a multi file downloader, multiple instantiations are required when more than a single file needs to be downloaded.

Each download has a download id, but that is not supplied to the Download class, to keep it independent from the other classes.

Now getting all the info from each instance of the file download and being able to control a single download, is the problem. How do I know which download is which?

Any solutions? Or design patterns you could recommend? I've hit a roadblock.

Download class:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace Mackerel_Download_Manager
{
    public class Download
    {
        public event EventHandler<DownloadStatusChangedEventArgs> ResumablityChanged;
        public event EventHandler<DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs> ProgressChanged;
        public event EventHandler Completed;

        public bool stop = true; // by default stop is true
        public bool paused = false;
        SemaphoreSlim pauseLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

        string filename;

        public void DownloadFile(Uri DownloadLink, string Path)
        {
            filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Path);

            stop = false; // always set this bool to false, everytime this method is called

            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(Path);
            long existingLength = 0;
            if (fileInfo.Exists)
                existingLength = fileInfo.Length;

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(DownloadLink);
            request.Proxy = null;
            request.AddRange(existingLength);

            try
            {
                using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    long fileSize = existingLength + response.ContentLength; //response.ContentLength gives me the size that is remaining to be downloaded
                    bool downloadResumable; // need it for not sending any progress

                    if ((int)response.StatusCode == 206) //same as: response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.PartialContent
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine("Resumable");
                        downloadResumable = true;
                    }
                    else // sometimes a server that supports partial content will lose its ability to send partial content(weird behavior) and thus the download will lose its resumability
                    {
                        if (existingLength > 0)
                        {
                            if (ResumeUnsupportedWarning() == false) // warn and ask for confirmation to continue if the half downloaded file is unresumable
                            {
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        existingLength = 0;
                        downloadResumable = false;
                    }
                    OnResumabilityChanged(new DownloadStatusChangedEventArgs(downloadResumable));

                    using (var saveFileStream = fileInfo.Open(downloadResumable ? FileMode.Append : FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        byte[] downBuffer = new byte[4096];
                        int byteSize = 0;
                        long totalReceived = byteSize + existingLength;
                        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                        while (!stop && (byteSize = stream.Read(downBuffer, 0, downBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            saveFileStream.Write(downBuffer, 0, byteSize);
                            totalReceived += byteSize;

                            float currentSpeed = totalReceived / (float)sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
                            OnProgressChanged(new DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs(totalReceived, fileSize, (long)currentSpeed));

                            pauseLock.Wait();
                            pauseLock.Release();
                        }
                        sw.Stop();
                    }
                }
                if (!stop) OnCompleted(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(e.Message, filename);
            }
        }

        public void pause()
        {
            if (!paused)
            {
                paused = true;
                // Note this cannot block for more than a moment
                // since the download thread doesn't keep the lock held
                pauseLock.Wait();
            }
        }

        public void unpause()
        {
            if (paused)
            {
                paused = false;
                pauseLock.Release();
            }
        }

        public void StopDownload()
        {
            stop = true;
            this.unpause();  // stop waiting on lock if needed
        }

        public bool ResumeUnsupportedWarning()
        {
            var messageBoxResult = System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("When trying to resume the download , Mackerel got a response from the server that it doesn't support resuming the download. It's possible that it's a temporary error of the server, and you will be able to resume the file at a later time, but at this time Mackerel can download this file from the beginning.\n\nDo you want to download this file from the beginning?", filename, System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
            if (messageBoxResult == System.Windows.MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnResumabilityChanged(DownloadStatusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var handler = ResumablityChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnProgressChanged(DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var handler = ProgressChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnCompleted(EventArgs e)
        {
            var handler = Completed;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }
    }

    public class DownloadStatusChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public DownloadStatusChangedEventArgs(bool canResume)
        {
            ResumeSupported = canResume;
        }
        public bool ResumeSupported { get; private set; }
    }

    public class DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs(long totalReceived, long fileSize, long currentSpeed)
        {
            BytesReceived = totalReceived;
            TotalBytesToReceive = fileSize;
            CurrentSpeed = currentSpeed;
        }

        public long BytesReceived { get; private set; }
        public long TotalBytesToReceive { get; private set; }
        public float ProgressPercentage 
        { 
            get 
            { 
                return ((float)BytesReceived / (float)TotalBytesToReceive) * 100; 
            } 
        }
        public float CurrentSpeed { get; private set; } // in bytes
        public TimeSpan TimeLeft
        {
            get
            {
                var bytesRemainingtoBeReceived = TotalBytesToReceive - BytesReceived;
                return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(bytesRemainingtoBeReceived / CurrentSpeed);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Download class is instantiated inside a Mackerel class, that starts the download for the given downloads.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace Mackerel_Download_Manager
{
    public static class Mackerel
    {
        //Main Menu functions
        public static void ResumeDownload(string[] DownloadIDs)
        {
            foreach (var DownloadID in DownloadIDs)
            {
                var itemToResume = Downloads.DownloadEntries.Where(download => download.DownloadID == DownloadID).FirstOrDefault();

                if (itemToResume.Running == false)
                {
                    itemToResume.Running = true;

                    var download = new Download();
                    download.DownloadFile(itemToResume.DownloadLink, itemToResume.SaveTo);
                    var window = new Dialogs.DownloadProgress(itemToResume);
                    window.Show();

                    double progress = 0;
                    itemToResume.Status = string.Format("{0:0.00}%", progress);

                    Downloads.DownloadEntries.CollectionChanged += delegate 
                    { 
                        if (!itemToResume.Running) window.Close(); 
                    };
                }
            }
        }

        public static void StopDownload(string[] DownloadIDs)
        {
            foreach (var DownloadID in DownloadIDs)
            {
                var itemToStop = Downloads.DownloadEntries.Where(download => download.DownloadID == DownloadID).FirstOrDefault();
                if (itemToStop.Running == true)
                    itemToStop.Running = false;
            }
        }

        public static void StopAllDownloads()
        {
            foreach (var itemToStop in Downloads.DownloadEntries.Where(download => download.Running == true))
                itemToStop.Running = false;
        }

        public static void RemoveDownload(string[] DownloadIDs) // this method is able to delete multiple downloads
        {
            foreach (var DownloadID in DownloadIDs)
            {
                // delete from the download list
                var selectedDownload = Downloads.DownloadEntries.Where(download => download.DownloadID == DownloadID).FirstOrDefault();
                var selectedDownloadIndex = Downloads.DownloadEntries.IndexOf(selectedDownload);
                Downloads.DownloadEntries.RemoveAt(selectedDownloadIndex);
                //delete from the harddrive
                if (File.Exists(selectedDownload.SaveTo))
                    File.Delete(selectedDownload.SaveTo);
            }
            Downloads.Serialize(); // save current state of object
        }

        public static void RemoveCompletedDownloads() // this method just removes all completed downloads from Mackerel's download list (it doesn't delete them from the hard drive)
        {
            foreach (var itemToRemove in Downloads.DownloadEntries.Where(download => download.Status == "Complete").ToList())
            {
                Downloads.DownloadEntries.Remove(itemToRemove);
            }
        }

        // Context Menu
        public static void OpenDownloadProperties(string DownloadID) // Open "Download Properties" for the given download ID
        {
            var DownloadProperties = new Dialogs.Context_Menu.DownloadProperties(DownloadID);
            DownloadProperties.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow; // so that this dialog centers to its parent window, as its window is set to WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
            DownloadProperties.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Full source code is here: https://github.com/Expenzor/mackerel-download-manager

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your making the download itself an object but are using "downloader" as the name instead. I would maybe suggest an array of downloaded objects or similar. The downloader class can have a method which creates a new object - perhaps a download object. Using an array or linked list etc will give you the opportunity to address the object and call them independently - know which is which.

Posting your code would help as well.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. How would I go about implementing this properly in code? I don't need the exact code. Just the general gist of what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: Maybe the Mackerel class should not be static. The constructor could take an argument for number of downloads to use and then create a collection of new 'download' objects while assigning an id to each. After this, you would be able to use the general push, pop type operations for adding and removing downloads. Does this sound legit?

Comment: There's no adding and removing downloads that needs to be done. Each Download object has methods that control each download, like pause, resume, stop. And every single download object constantly returns information for us to work with.  I need to create a List<Download> currentDownloads = new List<Download>(); This is something I already knew but messed up the first time and utterly confused myself. So embarrassing. There's no need to make the Mackerel class static, there's an easier way to do it. But thanks anyway. How could I be so stupid?!

Comment: It happens. Sometimes the best thing is to bounce it off of someone. A lot of the times you will answer yourself by trying to tell someone else about it.

Comment: StackOverflow probably isn't the best place to bounce it off of someone. :P But thanks for pushing me in the right direction :)